# python "binom" with fewer dependencies?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, lambda

My Python 3.6 script works great with

```
from scipy.special import binom
```

Running the code in AWS lambda, however, does not work. Attempting to load the zipped deployment package from S3 gives the error:

```
Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes
```

Surely somewhere there is a Python package which can do what "binom" does without needing all of "scipy" which seems to require "numpy" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The binomial coefficient is a known and fairly trivial calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient); `binom(n, k)` is just `n! / (k! * (n - k)!)`. Python built-ins can do this in a perfectly straightforward (if theoretically sub-optimal, since it can produce excessively large intermediates that more tuned approaches could avoid, but it hardly matters most of the time) way:

```
from math import factorial

def binom(n, k):
    return factorial(n) // (factorial(k) * factorial(n - k))
```

If you need it somewhat faster, [`gmpy2` offers a `bincoef` function](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mpz.html#mpz-functions), and `gmpy2` is a bit more standalone than `scipy`/`numpy` (it needs GMP/MPFR/MPC, but it's on the order of a few MB of binaries all told, not a few *hundred* MB). It returns a `gmpy2.mpz` type, which is largely interoperable with `int`, or you can just force conversion back to `int` by wrapping:

```
from gmpy2 import bincoef

def binom(n, k):
    return int(bincoef(n, k))
```